# Validate and process form in different routes, Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, process, routes, distinct

I'm doing a search page for my users. Form is displayed in the path /home and the collected data is sent to the path /search. There these are used to do a search which I show at /search. The problem is that if the form is processed at /search and there is any validation error the form is reloaded in /search and not at /home. Is there any way to get this?

```
//routing.yml

home:
path:  /
defaults: { _controller: UsuarioBundle:Default:home}

search:
path:  /search
defaults: { _controller: UsuarioBundle:Default:search}
```

.

```
//UsuarioBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

public function homeAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new UsuarioBusquedaType(), $usuario, array(
                                                                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('search'),
                                                                    'method' => 'POST',
                                                                    ));
return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:portada.html.twig', array('formulario' => $formulario->createView() ));
}

public function searchAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new UsuarioBusquedaType(), $usuario, array(
                                                                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('search'),
                                                                    'method' => 'POST',
                                                                    ));
    $formulario->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formulario->isValid()) {
         // Validate and search in DB
         return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:resultado.html.twig', array('usuarios' => $usuarios));
    }
    return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:portada.html.twig', array('formulario' => $formulario->createView() ));
```

I have also tried to do so: display the form and process it in the same path /home and then send the data through a redirection but I don’t know how to pass data to the new route. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if ($formulario->isValid()) {
     // Validate and search in DB
     return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Default:resultado.html.twig', array('usuarios' => $usuarios));
}
return $this->homeAction();
```

Comment: Call other controller does not change the path in which redisplays the form with validation errors. Therefore the form is shown in /search and that is not the desired behavior...

Comment: Do you NEED to submit the form to a different action? Symfony does what you want very well if you are using the same action to render the form and return validation errors.